# equalize the values by variables, taking into account the category and groups in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, lapply

In my data

```
#EDIT DPUT 
mydat=structure(list(ItemRelation = c(11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 
11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 
11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 
11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 
11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 
11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 
11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 
11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 
11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 
11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 
11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 
11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 
11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 
11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L), ReturnCount = c(0L, 2L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), DocumentNum = c(514L, 514L, 514L, 514L, 
514L, 514L, 514L, 514L, 514L, 514L, 514L, 514L, 514L, 514L, 514L, 
514L, 514L, 514L, 514L, 514L, 514L, 514L, 514L, 514L, 514L, 514L, 
514L, 514L, 514L, 514L, 514L, 514L, 514L, 514L, 514L, 514L, 514L, 
514L, 514L, 514L, 514L, 514L, 514L, 514L, 514L, 514L, 514L, 514L, 
514L, 514L, 514L, 514L, 896L, 896L, 896L, 896L, 896L, 896L, 896L, 
896L, 896L, 896L, 896L, 896L, 896L, 896L, 896L, 896L, 896L, 896L, 
896L, 896L, 896L, 896L, 896L, 896L, 896L, 896L, 896L, 896L, 896L, 
896L, 896L, 896L, 896L, 896L, 896L, 896L, 896L, 896L, 896L, 896L, 
896L, 896L, 896L, 896L, 896L, 896L, 896L, 896L, 896L, 896L, 896L, 
896L), IsPromo = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), CalendarYear = c(2018L, 
2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L), output = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, NA, NA, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, NA, NA, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L)), .Names = c("ItemRelation", "ReturnCount", "DocumentNum", 
"IsPromo", "CalendarYear", "output"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-104L))
```

I have group vars

```
ItemRelation    DocumentNum
11202                 514
11202                  96
```

There is Ispromo column. It can take values only 0 and 1.
So ReturnCount is numeric variable.

I need to replace the values of output column, by values of returncount `which go before 1 category of ispromo`.
It is mean that the values by zero category of ispromo which go before one category  of ispromo, for returncount and output colums must be same.
BUT, values of these columns `for zero category of ispromo AFTER one category`, we don't touch.
How to do it for each group ItemRelation+DocumentNum?

Cause desired output

## Edit expected output

```
    ItemRelation ReturnCount DocumentNum IsPromo output
1          11202           0         514       0      0
2          11202           2         514       0  **2**
3          11202           0         514       0      0
4          11202           0         514       0      0
5          11202           0         514       0      0
6          11202           0         514       0      0
7          11202           0         514       0      0
8          11202           0         514       0      0
9          11202           0         514       0      0
10         11202           0         514       0      0
11         11202           1         514       0  **1**
12         11202           0         514       0      0
13         11202           1         514       0  **1**
14         11202           1         514       0  **1**
15         11202           0         514       0      0
16         11202           0         514       0      0
17         11202           0         514       0      0
18         11202           0         514       0      0
19         11202           0         514       0      0
20         11202           0         514       0      0
21         11202           0         514       0      0
22         11202           0         514       0      0
23         11202           0         514       0      0
24         11202           0         514       0      0
25         11202           0         514       0      0
26         11202           0         514       0      0
27         11202           0         514       0      0
28         11202           1         514       0  **1**
29         11202           0         514       0      0
30         11202           0         514       0      0
31         11202           0         514       0      0
32         11202           0         514       0      0
33         11202           0         514       0      0
34         11202           0         514       0      0
35         11202           0         514       0      0
36         11202           0         514       1   <NA>
37         11202           0         514       1   <NA>
38         11202           0         514       0      0
39         11202           0         514       0      0
40         11202           0         514       0      0
41         11202           3         514       0      0
42         11202           0         514       0      0
43         11202           0         514       0      0
44         11202           0         514       0      0
45         11202           0         514       0      0
46         11202           1         514       0      1
47         11202           1         514       0      1
48         11202           0         514       0      0
49         11202           0         514       0      0
50         11202           0         514       0      0
51         11202           0         514       0      0
52         11202           0         514       0      0
53         11202           1         896       0  **1**
54         11202           0         896       0      0
55         11202           0         896       0      0
56         11202           0         896       0      0
57         11202           0         896       0      0
58         11202           0         896       0      0
59         11202           0         896       0      0
60         11202           0         896       0      0
61         11202           0         896       0      0
62         11202           0         896       0      0
63         11202           0         896       0      0
64         11202           0         896       0      0
65         11202           0         896       0      0
66         11202           0         896       0      0
67         11202           1         896       0  **1**
68         11202           0         896       0      0
69         11202           0         896       0      0
70         11202           0         896       0      0
71         11202           0         896       0      0
72         11202           0         896       0      0
73         11202           0         896       0      0
74         11202           0         896       0      0
75         11202           0         896       0      0
76         11202           0         896       0      0
77         11202           0         896       0      0
78         11202           0         896       0      0
79         11202           0         896       0      0
80         11202           3         896       0  **3**
81         11202           0         896       0      0
82         11202           0         896       0      0
83         11202           0         896       0      0
84         11202           0         896       0      0
85         11202           1         896       0  **1**
86         11202           1         896       0  **1**
87         11202           0         896       0      0
88         11202           0         896       1   <NA>
89         11202           0         896       1   <NA>
90         11202           0         896       0      0
91         11202           0         896       0      0
92         11202           0         896       0      0
93         11202           0         896       0      0
94         11202           0         896       0      0
95         11202           0         896       0      0
96         11202           0         896       0      0
97         11202           0         896       0      0
98         11202           0         896       0      0
99         11202           0         896       0      0
100        11202           0         896       0      0
101        11202           0         896       0      0
102        11202           0         896       0      0
103        11202           0         896       0      0
104        11202           0         896       0      0
```

** is marked the values of output by zero category of ispromo before one category of ispromo. I.e. we take value of returncount in this row and replace by it, the value of output in this row.

```
2          11202           2         514       0  **2**
```

for second row returncount =2 ,so 0 by output replaced by it.
Note this operation perform only for zero category of ispromo before 0ne category. AFTER one category, we don't touch zero category.

Comment: what do you mean by `category` ? please remove all your previous comments

Comment: @SalmanLashkarara ispromo means action 0 there is no action and 1 there is action. it is nominal var.

Comment: when i run your output, and your dataset, i dont see any change on `output`

Comment: @SalmanLashkarara, try now, please.

Comment: I just edited input data

Comment: @D.Joe Please, double check your data. Column `isPromo` contains only zeros. The is no "one category" in `isPromo` at all.

Comment: @Uwe, i edited post. Please check it.

Comment: IIUC, the expected `output` in rows 46 and 47 should be 0 as those rows come after the one category in this group? Currently, they are 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, there is always a contiguous streak of zeros in `IsPromo` followed by a streak of contiguous `1`s (called *one category* by the OP), and completed by a contiguous streak of zeros in each `ItemRelation`, `DocumentNum` group.

Then this can be solved by using the `rleid()` function and `update by reference`:

```
library(data.table)
# clean sample dataset: remove output column 
setDT(mydat)[, output := NULL]
# add grouping variable for ISPromo categories
setDT(mydat)[, promo.cat := rleid(IsPromo), by = .(ItemRelation, DocumentNum)][
  # copy only first category in each group
  promo.cat == 1L & IsPromo == 0L, output := ReturnCount][
    # remove helper column
    , promo.cat := NULL][]
mydat
```

> ```
>      ItemRelation ReturnCount DocumentNum IsPromo CalendarYear output
>   1:        11202           0         514       0         2018      0
>   2:        11202           2         514       0         2018      2
>   3:        11202           0         514       0         2018      0
>   4:        11202           0         514       0         2018      0
>   5:        11202           0         514       0         2018      0
>  ---                                                                 
> 100:        11202           0         896       0         2018     NA
> 101:        11202           0         896       0         2018     NA
> 102:        11202           0         896       0         2018     NA
> 103:        11202           0         896       0         2018     NA
> 104:        11202           0         896       0         2018     NA
> ```

```
# check 
mydat[ReturnCount > 0 & ReturnCount == output]
```

> ```
>     ItemRelation ReturnCount DocumentNum IsPromo CalendarYear output
>  1:        11202           2         514       0         2018      2
>  2:        11202           1         514       0         2018      1
>  3:        11202           1         514       0         2018      1
>  4:        11202           1         514       0         2018      1
>  5:        11202           1         514       0         2018      1
>  6:        11202           1         896       0         2018      1
>  7:        11202           1         896       0         2018      1
>  8:        11202           3         896       0         2018      3
>  9:        11202           1         896       0         2018      1
> 10:        11202           1         896       0         2018      1
> ```

These lines correspond to those marked by the OP in the expected result.

Comment: may i ask you help me with your function sales_action, because  after painstaking analysis, i found violation with sequences of zeros and ones.Please help,  check how can improve it.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52739874/replace-median-for-category-by-changing-condition-of-three-zero-before-and-three